# Prevent show first active tab on tab change bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have code:

```js
if (location.hash) {
  $('a[href=\'' + location.hash + '\']').tab('show');
}
var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
if (activeTab) {
  $('a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
}

$('body').on('click', 'a[data-toggle=\'tab\']', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var tab_name = this.getAttribute('href');
  if (history.pushState) {
    history.pushState(null, null, tab_name)
  }
  else {
    location.hash = tab_name
  }
  localStorage.setItem('activeTab', tab_name)

  $(this).tab('show');
  return false;
});
$(window).on('popstate', function () {
  var anchor = location.hash ||
    $('a[data-toggle=\'tab\']').first().attr('href');
  $('a[href=\'' + anchor + '\']').tab('show');
});
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    


<ul class="nav" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">This is home tab</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">This is profile tab</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">This is contact tab</div>
</div>
```

How I can prevent show first active tab, when page reloading with other tab? My tabs save on localstorage, and when I reload page with other tab, he's first display me first tab, and between my tab. How I can prevent this bug?

Comment: I tested this code and it seems to behave fine. Can you elaborate/rephrase what issue you're facing?

Comment: @Jeto Sorry, I not use class `nav-tabs`, I use custom class, remove please this class and check now.

Comment: So to be sure, your issue is that it displays the first tab for a split second before displaying the right one, is that correct?

Comment: @Jeto, yea, of course

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `active` (but keep the `show`) class from your tabs (both the links and the tabs themselves).

Also, change your "default" (on page load) script to this:

```
if (location.hash) {
    $('a[href="' + location.hash + '"]').tab('show');
} else {
    activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
    if (activeTab) {
        $('a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
    } else {
        $('#home').addClass('active');
    }
}
```

Because for some reason, using `$('a[href="#home"]').tab('show');` won't work on page load (it won't show its contents), which has got to be a bug. `$('#home').addClass('active');` will add back the `active` class to your default tab instead (only if there is no tab hash in the URL and nothing in `localStorage` either).